# Insert method from keyboard

Tags: algorithm, sorting, vector, insert, cin

sorted.txt file contains ascending strings. Write these strings in the appropriate specification vector, and then paste the string entered from the keyboard into the vector so that the sort sequence obtained is not disturbed.

Comment: so, what is that you don't understand/struggle with?

Comment: Can you write me a code?

Comment: this platform isn't a code writing service. You need to show what you have done and ask specific questions about what problems you are facing.

Comment: #include <iostream> #include <fstream> #include <vector> #include <algorithm> #include <string> using namespace std; void printVector(vector<string>); int maun() { vector<string>v; string words; string m; fstream fin("sorted.txt"); while (fin >> words) v.push_back(words); printVector(v); v.insert(v.end() + 1, m); cin >> m; sort(v.begin(), v.end()); printVector(v); } void printVector(vector<string>x) { for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) cout << x[i] << ' '; cout << endl; }

Comment: I could not understand why it does not work. This is my first time on this platform and forgive me if I asked anything wrong

Comment: no problem, please edit your post and add your current solution with some example input and expected output. Also explain what you guess the problem is and show what the current output of the code on the example input is. This will help potential helpers to understand the problem and chime int.